# When I use the following script with selenium and Beautifulsoup the text is correctly extracted but the json files is always the same

Tags: json, selenium, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I have created the script below to extract the text from the posts of an instagram user profile.

It works perfectly to extract the posts but there is a problem once i start using the scroll function of selenium as the json file does not seem to be updating.

I have created a loop for 2 repetitions for test purposes
but there seems to be a problem in the line `pageSource=driver.page_source`.
I am expecting the script to load the new json file linked to the new page that but when I test it the pageSource file is always the same even if selenium is correctly scrolling through the page.

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
import json

url = #instagram url

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)


for n in range(2):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,      document.body.scrollHeight);")
    pageSource=driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(pageSource, 'html.parser')
    body = soup.find('body')
    script = body.find('script')
    raw = script.text.strip().replace('window._sharedData =', '').replace(';', '')

    json_data=json.loads(raw)
    for post in json_data['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]['graphql']['user']['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']['edges']:
        text_src = post['node']['edge_media_to_caption']['edges'][0]['node']['text']
        print (text_src)

    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Do you see the updated json values when you checked manually after scrolling the page?

Comment: Checked now manually. no the json values are not updated after scrolling the page. But i don't know why.

Comment: Check the network tab to see from where it's getting the data.